# Take a range of values from collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given a list such as this...

```
string[] fields = new[]
{
     "Value1", 
     "TableStart:Value2", 
     "Value3", 
     "Value4", 
     "TableEnd:Value2", 
     "Value5", 
     "Value6"
};
```

Is there a way I can retrieve all information between the "TableStart" and "TableEnd" statements without writing a loop?  I thought Linq might have some way of achieving this but I could not come up with one.

In the example above I would expect a list containing "Value3" and "Value4".

Comment: LINQ is implemented with loops. Do you mean you want to avoid writing the loop yourself?

Comment: @Oded Yes.  I like the brevity of Linq so I try to use it when possible (but not over use it) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe:

```
var result = fields.SkipWhile(s => !s.Contains("TableStart"))
                   .Skip(1)
                   .TakeWhile(s => !s.Contains("TableEnd"))
                   .ToList();
```

But i would prefer a simple loop instead.

Comment: Cant we use Enumerable.Range??

Comment: @RahulTripathi - How would that be of any use? It generates a sequence of numbers.

Comment: I am going to accept this as the answer because first, your Linq statement works and second, I agree with your last statement.  Thx for your feedback.